# Problem with updating MikTeX 21.2 on Windows 10 X64 computer right after installation

Tags: errors, miktex, updating

I am facing this problem where I can not update MikTeX 21.2 right after installation. I have uninstalled and reinstalled MikTeX to no avail. I do not have any apps open but my computer is connected to OneDrive when I updated. After I updated I can not compile my LaTeX files in TexStudio as it generates an error message. I saw a similar question here to mine but there was no definite answer, I think. Please do help

This is the error message that I get in MikTeX when I try to update.

```
fileName="C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe", exitCode="1"


GENERAL MIKTEX INFORMATION
ReportDate: 2021-04-15 16:10:27
CurrentVersion: 21.2
SetupDate: 2021-04-15 15:59:00
SetupVersion: 21.2
Configuration: Regular
GitInfo: 7a7e645 / 2021-02-20 10:38:14
OS: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, build 19042
SharedSetup: no
LinkTargetDirectory: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
PathOkay: no
LastUpdateCheck: 2021-04-15 16:00:30
LastUpdate: 2021-04-15 16:09:50
LastUpdateDb: 2021-04-15 16:00:22
SystemAdmin: yes
RootPrivileges: no
AdminMode: no
Root0: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
Root1: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
Root2: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
Root3: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Root4: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
UserInstall: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
UserConfig: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
UserData: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\MiKTeX
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX
Invokers: non-existing/cmd

ERROR DETAILS
Program: miktex-fc-cache.exe
Error: The executed process did not succeed.
Details: 
  fileName: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe
  exitCode: 1
```

Comment: What do you get if you call `fc-cache -v` on a command line?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer 
`C:\Users\bells>fc-cache -v    
C:/WINDOWS/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1154 fonts, 0 dirs    
C:/WINDOWS/fonts: failed to write cache    
C:/WINDOWS/Cache/Fontcache: not cleaning non-existent cache directory    
fc-cache: failed`

Comment: `C:/WINDOWS/Cache/Fontcache` sounds very odd. Open an issue at the miktex github.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer  I realised that I had run the code you specified in command prompt when I had reinstalled MikTeX without updating the packages. Once I updated MiKTeX and ran the code you specified in command prompt, I got a whole lot of error messages in 4 dialog boxes saying code execution could not proceed because MikTex210200-app.dll, MikTex210200-getopt.dll, MikTex210200-fontconfig.dll, MikTex210200-core.dll was not found.  Was advised to reinstall program

Comment: I had uninstalled and reinstalled but to no avail. It won't update without error

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, still same issue with the error with updating

Comment: Did you use the basic installer for the installation?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I used the "basic TeX/LaTeX system on Windows installer"

Comment: Try on a command line `initexmf --mklinks --verbose --force`. If that doesn't help  try to install with the netinstaller, in another posting someone said that worked for him.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I ran the command on the command line and it seems to work. I could run my LaTeX files on TexStudio so MikTeX was working again although there were no more packages to update. However when I compile and run my LaTeX file, when it needs to install packages, I get this warning message `Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "exercise2-1-1".tex

Unfortunately, the package geometry could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\bells\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
Process exited normally`

When I recompiled, it ran normally

Comment: If you have the disc space simply install all packages directly. Then you don't have to handle on-the-fly installation problems and can work on your latex files.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Would there be a problem with the above warning message? I recompiled the same tex file and process exited normally and seemed to run. Please advise.

Comment: I don't know, but if geometry is now there and can be used it should imho be fine.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Can you provide me with the link or download to install all the packages? I am afraid I am rather new to LaTeX

Comment: open the miktex console, go to the package tab and select some packages and click on the +.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for your help. Really appreciate your time and effort to help me as I am new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I stumbled in the same problem (fc-cache returning an error every time I tried to update a package).
looking the logs, the error seemed to be around c:\windows\Cache and c:\windows\Cache\Fontcache (which were non existent in my system), so I just created those (as administrator, note, my user account is a 'standard' one). the error message changed a bit, but remained. then, as an administrator, I gave my user account writing rights to those dirs (in fact, full access to just c:\windows\Cache). "problem solved" no more error messages from fc-cache.
so, fc-cache wants/needs write access to c:\windows\Cache, which is not an issue if your user account has admin rights (which is a no-no for security reasons).
MikTeX version 21.8